Android FCM : Messages Stop Being Delivered to Topics with condition
After installing the Android app, I subscribe to several FCM topics.
I send 2-3 messages per hour using condition with topics via REST API:
  "message": {
    "condition" : "'reg83' in topics || 'reg11' in topics || 'reg81' in topics",
    "data": {
      "qcode": "1730777677#code"
    },
    "android":{
      "priority": "high",
      "ttl":"2280s",
      "direct_boot_ok": true
    },
  }

Messages are delivered only in the first 8-12 hours after app installation.
After, message delivery to topics stops working.
(even sending to a topic without "condition" stops working)
(Sending from the backend occurs without errors)
Important:

The app's notifications are not blocked;
The app is in the Active appStandBy bucket;
The firebase token is active (message delivery via token works);
FCM limits and quotas are not violated;
FCM-monitor *#*#426#*#* - doesn't show a delivery.

Can anyone tell me what the reason is?

I also encountered this issue recently, and still unable to resolve the problem.
It could be better if we can share information to Firebase Support for investigation.

I encountered the same issue—notifications sent via token work fine, but those sent via topic do not. However, after reinstalling the app, the notifications were successfully delivered. This may be related to the FCM token, though I'm not entirely sure why. Could you try reinstalling the app on your end and let me know if that resolves the issue? I'm also working on identifying the root cause on my side.

I too am having this issue on Android 14/ Samsung S23U, iPad 9thGen and iPadPro12.5 both using iOS18. I've revised code etc. I'm going to have to code so that I can set a flag to use tokens if ever needed although the Topic is much more efficient. Either that or failover to SMS, but the messages get accepted by Google... just not processed so not sure how I'd determine a failover.
Update
I had been overwriting the app. Uninstalling and reinstalling got it functional on Android.
Deleting from iOS devices and redeploying has also rectified the issue on 2 iOS devices.

"This might be because the FCM device token you generated has expired. Since the topic is associated with the device token, you should regenerate the device token and then re-subscribe to the topic. This may resolve the issue."

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Now you may find an update of the incident A small subset of registrations cannot receive topic messaging at Firebase Status Dashboard
